# iPhone upgraded to iOS 11 - retrieve log data from an old incompatible app called "Articles"

Tags: iphone, upgrade

I mistakenly upgraded my iPhone to iOS 11.4.1, and my Wikipedia app called [Articles](https://itunes.apple.com/app/articles/id364881979), which I've been using for 8 years or so, is now no longer compatible.

Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve or extract my search log from this app? I just want a plain-text list with all my search terms and their date.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple possibilities.

You can backup your iPhone using iTunes, and then try restoring your iPhone's backup to another iPhone that is running an older iOS version.

You can backup your iPhone to a Mac using iTunes with encryption turned off, and try using one of the (paid?) Mac utilities that can read unencrypted iOS backup files in the iTunes backup directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it won't be possible. It will no longer be possible to launch the app on your iPhone. Neither can you downgrade the iOS now.

The said app is 32-bit only. iOS 11 does not support launching and installing 32-bit only apps. After upgrading to iOS 11 from a previous version, any installed 32-bit stops working.

If the said app supports file sharing & stores it's log in accessible manner inside the app bundle, you can attempt to recover those files by connecting your iPhone to Mac/PC and retrieve the files from within iTunes.

**Note**: To resume access to the app and to **potentially** re-gain access to your user data, it is advisable to contact the developer and request them to update the app with support for 64-bit so that the app can continue working with iOS 11 and later.

Comment: @JensChr.Opdahl Kindly accept the answer if it worked for you. That will be helpful for other users having similar query.